# how to redirect back 2 pages after add to cart in Cart Throb

Tags: cartthrob, redirects, redirection

I am trying to redirect a user back 2 pages after they add an item to the cart.

Is there any plugins or dynamic methods that would make this work?

Answer (score 2):

check out this add-on http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables and it's "Page Tracker" variables that you can use!